# How to save several same entity in my list with Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have next entity Program:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "program_action",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "program_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "action_id"))
private List<Action> actions;
```

and "Actions" that can be duplicated in the list.
I want to keep this list to database but get exception:
Duplicate entry '' for key 'UK_nudt643x8s4vnku9adpd2hujp'

example "program_action" table:
1 _ 2
1 _ 1
1 _ 2

```
public class Action {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "time")
private int time; //in seconds

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "description", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String description;
```

}

```
@Service
public void save(Program program) throws Exception {
    repository.save(program);
}

@Controller
@PostMapping
public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("program") Program program, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
    try {
        log.info("Save - ok!");
        service.save(program);
    } catch (Exception e){
        log.info("Save failed. Message: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    return "redirect:/program/all";
}
```

I understand that there is a key preventing me from doing this but i dont find how to fix it with Hibernate.

I hope someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: could you please add the code where you try to save this list to database?

Comment: could you provide the `Action` entity code?

Comment: Sure! I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this problem.
Firstly,  @OneToMany does not require @JoinTable
Secondly,  I have given up on automatic generation database and built schemes with Flyway.